# Why do we need to take epsilon for a half closed interval?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm going through Billingsley and trying to nail down why one method of proof doesn't work (or if it does then why it isn't the standard proof).

First note that we have defined a set, $A$, to be of measure zero/be negligible if there exists a collection $I_k$ such that two conditions hold (for any $\epsilon > 0$):

1. $A \subset \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$
2. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |I_k| < \epsilon$

Where $I_k = (a_k, b_k]$ and $|I_k| = |b_k - a_k|$.

Let's say I want to prove that all countable sets are of measure zero. I can do this by first showing that a singleton is of measure zero and then saying that a countable set is a countable union of disjoint sets of measure zero so their sum must be of measure zero as well (since it would clearly be covered by the union of the singletons and the sum of $0$ countably many times is $0$).

I have three methods that all seem valid.

1. My first instinct is to say that each set $\{a_k\}$ is covered by an interval $(a_k - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+2}}, a_k + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+2}}]$. Each of these intervals is of length $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{k+1}}$ so the sum of all $|I_k| = \epsilon\sum_k\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} = \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$. Thus this sum of singletons is less than $\epsilon$ and it covers countable $A$ so $A$ is negligible.
2. Don't do it for all of the intervals and just say the set $\{a\}$ is covered by $(a_k - \frac{\epsilon}{2}, a_k + \frac{\epsilon}{2}]$. This interval is of length $\epsilon$, but $\epsilon$ arbitrary so this set is negligible and then we can use the argument I made above to say that this extends to countable sets.
3. This is the one that I feel like should work, but feels too easy. Why can't I say each $\{a_k\}$ is covered by the set $I_k = (a_k, a_k]$ and then $|I_k| = |a_k - a_k| = 0$ and then boom $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 0 < \epsilon$. Normally, you would have to avoid this because we would have open intervals and in that case the limiting argument seems unavoidable, but in this case we have half closed intervals so it seems like we should be able to just say that $a_k \subset (a_k, a_k]$ (this feels bad, but seems like it should be fine, even though the left side is "wrong" in that it IS in the set so the open piece is false)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Any comments on the benefits/errors in 1/2 are welcome as well!!

Comment: The set $(a,a]$ is the empty set.

Comment: Yeah that was eventually what I was thinking, but I feel like there should be a difference between $(a, a)$ and $(a, a]$. Is there none?

Comment: Go check their definitions. There might be some spiritual difference, or if you were thinking about how they might behave under small perturbations, but basically no, they are just different ways of writing the empty set, along with $(5,3)$ or $(5,3]$.